# Use of iron oxide as surface cleaning agent

Tags: industrial-engineering

Metal oxides are hard in nature, that's what my professor says. Technically  Iron oxide is a metal oxide and must be hard.

Then **is it used in industries for surface finishing operations like buffing?** If not, why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like metals and minerals, metal oxides have different grades of hardness depending on a lot more than just its chemical components. Crystal structure is the main factor here. Consider carbon, for example: both graphite and diamond are chemically carbon, but one is used as a lubricant and the other for cutting and grinding. Similarly, just the fact that something is a metal oxide doesn't mean it's well suited for use as an abrasive and for similar processes like buffing and polishing. Apart from crystal structure, particle size and shape are also factors to be considered.

Hence, iron oxide is, to the best of my knowledge, rarely or never used as an industrial abrasive. Aluminium oxide, on the other hand, is. Aluminum oxide comes in various forms, from alumina to carborundum.

Comment: I know aluminium oxide is used in industry. Q-carbon is likely to be used in future. Iron rust is used for polishing gold ornaments. However iron rust not used in industry.

Comment: What is exact reason?   Is finish not good? Or maybe operation time is large? Or iron oxide is not hard enough to be used as abrasive powder?

Answer (score 1):

[Jeweller's rouge](http://www.cooksongold.com/Jewellery-Tools/Jewellers-Rouge-Powder-120g4oz-prcode-998-193) is fine Iron III oxide. It is generally used for fine polishing of relatively soft metals like gold and silver as well as some plastics and minerals.

It isn't aggressive enough  to be used on harder metals like steel except perhaps for very fine specialist polishing operations. Consider that aluminium oxide typically forms a hard, stable layer on metal whereas rust has very friable structure.

Aluminium oxide is one of the most widely used general purpose abrasives (usually colour coded brown), zirconium oxide is used for more aggressive stock removal at larger grit sizes (usually colour coded blue) and other high performance 'ceramic' abrasives (colour coded red) are sometimes used for stock removal on hard to grind materials.

As well as their hardness the performance of different abrasives depends on how the particle wear for example aluminium oxide tend to become smoother as it is used which can be good for surface finishing whereas zirconium tends to fracture and so retains an aggressive cut for longer making it more effective for stock removal especially at larger grit sizes but at grits higher than about 120 the is no significant advantage over aluminium oxide.

Diamond grit may be used for some applications, especially lapping and honing of hard metals either as a paste or embedded in a metal substrate.

There are also various proprietary compounds, typically an abrasive powder blended with grease or wax used for specific buffing operations on specific metals.